# socat does not terminate the udp client when server side exit

Tags: socat

server side:

```
socat udp-l:2023,reuseaddr,fork exec:/bin/bash,pty,setsid,setpgid,stderr,ctty
```

client side:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0 udp:localhost:2023
```

When I exit the bash, the server side exit, but the client does not exit.

```
[root@udp-server-v1-9cdc7f96f-pwdjq /]# exit
exit
^C[root@udp-server-v1-9cdc7f96f-pwdjq /]#
```

If I press any key after this, socat will connect to the server again. ps -ef shows that server side forks a new bash, it's a new connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is connectionless. There is no notification sent to the client when the server exits.

If you want this behavior -- and if you want reliable delivery of data -- use TCP, not UDP.